# Passport.js stateless/sessionless google auth

Tags: node.js, api, express, passport.js, passport-google-oauth2

I want to write a stateless node api with passport.js for authentication.

I want to create an oauth google api endpoint that returns the api key on success and other details on success.

Google API route

```
router.get('/',passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email']}));


router.get('/callback', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('google', { session: false, failureRedirect: '/#/login'}, function(err, user, info) {
        console.log('------------------in google callback-----------------');
        if (err) res.status(500).json({status_code: 500, message: "Authentication error", data : err});

        if (!user) {
             res.status(404).json({status_code: 404, message : "User not found/created"});
        }
        var token = 'JWT KEY TO USE AS API TOKEN'; 
        res.status(200).json({status_code: 200, message : "Success", data : {token : token, user:user }});
    })(req, res, next);

});
```

When i open my api endpoint in browser on successfull authentication the json response is just printed on the screen and i have no way to capture the same in a variable. Calling the same api endpoint via ajax doesn't work.

[This is how i recieve the json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX0Yg.jpg)

> How do i create a google login api endpoint that works without
>   sessions and returns a token?

How can i run this via ajax? Is there any way to call this api end point and recieve the response in a success callback?

Answer (score 1):

The Google authentication process needs to happen in the client (so the browser will always open that new page) and then the Google server needs to contact your server directly (at your callback endpoint), otherwise the client could just pretend they were authenticated.

So if you are trying to do this in a single request to your server or without a server, that is not possible.